# Filter by age using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Good morning, fellow programmers. I would like to enquire this doubt: How can I filter the data coming from my database using the parameter age. In the line belows you can find the code I've written to the date:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" id="age" name="age">
                    <option selected  disabled>Age</option>
                    <option>All</option>
                    <option value="18-34">18-34</option>
                    <option value="35">35+</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

In the following lines you will find the php enclosed in my business logic:

```
     if($age && $age  != "" && $age != "All") {
            $query->where(function ($q) use($age) {
              $range = explode('-',$age);
              $q->whereBetween('birthday', [$minDate, $maxDate]);
            });
        }
```

I would like to express my gratitude to all of you and wish you the best to all of you and your families.

Comment: What's the exact problem? Are you asking for code review or ...?

Comment: Im asking on how to filter by age. My code is this one but it doesn't work thats why I am asking experts to help me

Comment: What you getting with this code?

Comment: I don't know bro I just saw this in the net

Answer (score 1):

I assume `birthday` is a date. Then you can do use Carbon's [`subYears()`](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) method:

```
if (!empty($age) && $age !== 'All') {
    $range = explode('-', $age);

    if (count($range) > 1) {
        $q->whereBetween('birthday', [now()->subYears($range[0]), now()->subYears($range[1])]);
    } else {
        $q->where('birthday', '<', now()->subYears($range[0]))
    }
}
```

Comment: Bra it's shows here that period is undefine variable

Comment: @gwapo read the code again, please. You may also want to change the code, it's just showing you the idea.